# How to render CSRF input in twig?

Tags: php, symfony, csrf, twig

I know there's the usual way to render CSRF token hidden input with `form_rest`, but is there a way to render **just** CSRF input itself? I've overridden `{% block field_widget %}` in theme to render a piece of additional text. But as CSRF token is rendered in input field too and I got a piece of text I don't need next to a hidden field. So I'd like to render it separately with an argument that tells it not to render this text.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

you can do it with `{{ form_widget(formView._token) }}`

Answer (score 55):

If you have `formView` object, you can render it using Twig function:

```
{{ form_widget(formView._token) }}
```

If you haven't - you can render token without using form object directly:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ csrf_token('some-name') }}">
```

Works in Symfony 2.x and 3.x

To validate the token you can use the following code in your controller (Symfony 3.x):

```
$submittedToken = $request->request->get('token');

if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('some-name', $submittedToken)) {
    // ... do something,
}
```

Comment: Nice to know, sometimes this is very useful feature

Comment: Sorry, did not work for me :( I got "CSRF tokens can only be generated if a CsrfTokenManagerInterface is injected in FormRenderer::__construct()." in Symfony 3.1. But which FormRenderer? I don't want to use any form.

Comment: This works for me in Symfony 3.2. although, you made a statement that _'authenticate' is supposed to be the form name_. I don't think this is true. It should always be '**authenticate**' if you are using it for login. Check [official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/csrf_in_login_form.html) for this.

Comment: @NiketPathak Thanks, updated the answer with new information

Answer (score 21):

Or you can just simply use this :

```
{{ form_row(form._token) }}
```

This will automatically generate the proper hidden HTML elements, ie the proper HTML structure and field names, according to the type of form you're using.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to render the csrf input inside Twig so that I could use it for ***Delete*** operations.
Using `{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}` as per @YuryPliashkou's answer gives me the incorrect token (one which is only valid for logins!)

What worked for me was this **`{{ csrf_token('form') }}`** which gives me the correct csrf token which I would then pass to my controller via ajax.

```
<span id="csrf_token" data-token="{{ csrf_token('form') }}"></span> 
// my ajax call
$.ajax({
    url: localhost/admin/product/4545,   // 4545->id of the item to be deleted
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        "_method": "DELETE",
        "form[_token]": $("#csrf_token").data("token")   // passed csrf token here
    },
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something 
   }
});
```

Verified its working on **Symfony 3.x.**

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43011678/4717533)

Answer (score 1):

didn't find  solution worked for me, finded and tested and worked for my Simfony3 value="{{ _token }}" in example

```
     <form name="form" method="post" action="{{ path('blog_show', { 'id': blog.id }) }}">
       <input name="_method" value="DELETE" type="hidden">
       <input class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" type="submit">
       <input id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="{{ _token }}" type="hidden">
    </form>
```

more about scrf  can be viewed here: [Creating forms manually in Symfony2, but still use its CSRF and isValid() functionalily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245059/creating-forms-manually-in-symfony2-but-still-use-its-csrf-and-isvalid-functi)