# Symfony 2 - Delete Forms and CSRF Token

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, twig, csrf

I have a List of entries coming from a database. I would like to have a "Delete-Button" at the end of every row, so that the user won't have to first go to the edit/show page to delete the entry.

I tried creating a hidden input field with the csrf token like so:

```
return $this->createFormBuilder()
   ->getForm()
;
```

this will output:

```
<div id="form">
   <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="6c98ebfa9df07.....">
</div>
```

The rest of the Form i put around in the twig template so that every form has its own action path according the the id of the entry.

unfortunately in the twig template only the first

```
{{ form_widget(delete_form) }}
```

will get rendered.

How can i use this hidden field more often?
OR is there any way to do this whole thing differently?

Thanks for any help

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForms();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('IntranetServicesBundle:Laender')->findAll();

        return $this->render('IntranetServicesBundle:Laender:index.html.twig', array(
            'entities' => $entities,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }


private function createDeleteForms()
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('id', 'hidden')
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
```

Comment: Can't you just create a route like `object/delete/{id}` and make it go to the delete action of your controller? You then just need to add a `<a>` link with this route and you are good. Or do you want something more sophisticated?

Comment: yeah, that would work, but I do want the csrf protection....

Answer (score 3):

You may render individual tokens with:

```
{{ form_widget(form._token) }}
```

or specifically for your case:

```
{{ form_widget(delete_form._token) }}
```

But, I think you are better served making an array of forms and fully rendering each one:

In your controller:

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $rep= $em->getRepository('IntranetServicesBundle:Laender')
                ->createQueryBuilder('l');

        var_dump($rep->getQuery()->getDql());
        $entities=$rep->getQuery()->getResult();

        $delete_forms  = array_map(
            function($element){ 
                return $this->createDeleteForm($element->getId());}
            ,$entities->toArray()
            );

        return $this->render('IntranetServicesBundle:Laender:index.html.twig'
                           , array(
                                 'entities'        => $entities,
                                 'delete_forms'    => $delete_forms
                           ));
    }


private function createDeleteForms($id)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder(array('id' => $id)))
        ->add('id', 'hidden')
        ->getForm()
    ;
}

public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('IntranetServicesBundle:Laender')
                     ->find($id);
        // this line might need to be changed to point to the proper repository

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Laender entity.');
        }

        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('laender_index'));
    // this line might need to be changed to point to the proper 
    // post-delete route
}
```

In your twig do something along the lines of:

```
{% for form in delete_forms %}{{form_widget(form)}}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: hmm. this throws a "FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\Query::map()..."

Comment: it's not working either. $entities is an object, so it can't work with array_map :-(

Comment: what kind of object is it?  I'm a little surprised it is not a collection.  Added an edit in case it is a collection (to toArray() call)

Comment: FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\Query::toArray() in 
Maybe I'll just do it without the csrf token and a regular link.... :-(

Comment: I didn't know the repository call returned a query.  Hmm.  Edited above.

Comment: FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object in

Comment: Doh.  Type in $entities=$rep->getQuery->getResult();  should get getQuery().  editted

Comment: try var_dumping the dql and seeing  if the query is right.  Editted above

Comment: string(54) "SELECT l FROM Intranet\ServicesBundle\Entity\Laender l"

Comment: Is that an object in your database?  All evidence points to you not having this entity.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you mean :/

Comment: The query should not fail.  Something is missing from your explanation, or something is configured wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of @Lighthart led me to the correct answer:

In your controller generate an array of form views and had it over to the view:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Entity')->findAll();

    $delete_forms = array_map(
        function ($element) {
            return $this->createDeleteForm($element->getId())->createView();
        }
        , $entities
    );

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Entity:index.html.twig', array(
        'entities' => $entities,
        'delete_forms' => $delete_forms
    ));
}
```

Now you have to access this in your view. Therefore you can use the form functions and the special loop variables:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% for entity in entities %}
        {# Access the delete form for this entity using the loop index ... #}
        {% set delete_form = delete_forms[loop.index0] %}

        {# ... and display the form using the form tags. #}
        {{ form_start(delete_form) }}
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
        {{ form_end(delete_form) }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation where I wanted to delete a product while using csrf protection. I also wanted to use **ajax** to make the DELETE request.

#### Tested for Symfony 3.x

So, to do this, this is what my **view**, *index.html*, looked like:

```
// html for displaying a products table with delete btn for each row
// ...
// Retrieve csrf token and store it somewhere in DOM (preferably outside table), 
// We do this so that we can send the token via ajax later
<span id="csrf_token" data-token="{{ csrf_token('form') }}"></span> 
<script>
// Make an ajax request on the on-click handler of our delete btn
$.ajax({
    url: localhost/admin/product/4545,   // generated dynamically, the last segment being the ID of the item to be deleted.
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        "_method": "DELETE",
        "form[_token]": $("#csrf_token").data("token")   // passed csrf token here
    },
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something with the result
   }
});
</script>
```

As seen above, **`{{ csrf_token('form') }}`** is what is actually giving you the **csrf token inside twig.**

My **Controller**:

```
/**
 * Deletes a product entity.
 * @Route("/{id}", name="admin_product_delete")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, product $product)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($product);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($product);
            $em->flush($product);
            // you can return a json response here to your ajax callback if you'd like.
            return new JsonResponse(array('status' => 'deleted'));
        }
    // return new JsonResponse(array('status' => 'failed'));
}

/**
 * Creates a form to delete a product entity.
 * @param product $product The product entity
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createDeleteForm(product $product)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('admin/product/{id}', array('id' => $product->getId())))
        ->setMethod('DELETE')
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
```

And this should delete the required row as expected!

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Phidelux led me to the following solution:

In twig I created delete form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ path('page_delete', {'id': page.id}) }}" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token('delete' ~ page.id) }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-icon">
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

The code for creating a list view is:

```
/**
     * @Route("/", name="page-list", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(PageRepository $pageRepository): Response
    {
        $pages = $pageRepository->findAll();
        $delete_forms = array_map(
            function ($element) {
                return $this->render('admin/page/_delete_form.html.twig', [
                    'page' => $element,
                ]);

            }
            , $pages
        );
        return $this->render('admin/page/index.html.twig', [
            'pages' => $pages,
            'delete_forms' => $delete_forms
        ]);
    }
```

Then in my list view I added the delete button:

```
{% for key, page in pages %}
...
    {{ delete_forms[key].content | raw }}
{% endfor %}
```

And in my edit page form I can use:

```
{{ include('admin/sjabloon/_delete_form.html.twig') }}
```

This solved the method not allowed message on delete