# Creating forms manually in Symfony2, but still use its CSRF and isValid() functionalily

Tags: symfony

OK, I googled this hard, but everything I find talks about Symfony forms in context of regular Symfony form processing (e.g. form_widget(), creating FormType class, etc.). I have many such forms in my Symfony project, they work great.

**BUT:**

I also have some pretty complex AJAX forms that I would like to build manually (using plain old HTML and JS). I do still want to utilize Symfony's Form validation capabilities and CSRF protection. However, for some reason I can't get CSRF working when using isValid() for **manually** created forms.

This is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

In my view controller I set _token:

```
$_token = $this->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('form');
```

In my view (**manually** created form) (getting _token from my view controller):

```
<html>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="form[_token]" value="{{ _token }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="form[id]" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</html>
```

In my action controller (when form submitted, I am TRYING to do the following):

```
//Create form (for validation purposes)
$form = $this->get('form.factory')
  ->createBuilder('form', array('id' => $request->get('id')))
  ->add('id', 'hidden')
  ->getForm();

//Bind form
$form->bind($request)

//Validate form
if($form->isValid()) {
  //... save data
}

//Return response...
```

For some reason I can't get isValid() working, I suspect that my _token is thing not properly used, but I am out of ideas why. Have anyone actually made manually forms work with Symfony components? Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make this work?

Basically, what I want to accomplish is:

1. Manually create HTML form (with CSFR protection and **without** TWIG form widget functions)
2. Use Symfony's form functionality to validate that form

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're mismatching the **intention** here (argument passed to your CSRF provider). I tried generating form as you wrote above and break-pointed the generation of token. The value was `unknown`.

So, try passing `unknown` instead of `form` to your `generateCsrfToken` call and hopefully it should work. ;)

### EDIT:

I have just finished some digging and it now does make perfect sense.

Look at the class `FormTypeCsrfExtension`. Apparently, it's the default extension used for CSRF token protection. On the line `#80` (might not be this one exactly in your case) there is method `setDefaultOptions` that is usually overridden in your form types. Anyhow, there is a default options called `intention` that has a value of `unknown` ==> the one we are seeing here.

My guess is that you could easily override this option in your own form type just by passing `intention` and setting your own value (just as you would pass `csrf_protection` => false when you would want to disable CSRF protection altogether).

Comment: OK. Doing so, worked. Thanks. But now I don't understand why. I looked at the API for generateCsrfToken() for details on the intention parameter, but it's still not clear to me why passing 'unknown' for an intention parameter works. I guess what I need to know is how properly use intentions? Thanks.

Comment: yeah, it's is a bit unclear to me as well. I would assume some more meaningful default value :)

Comment: I am digging through Symfony's code but cannot find any code that would make 'form' fail and 'unknown' work. Maybe someone else can explain what's going on with this..?

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer with some findings about this default value :)

Comment: I just tried your suggestion regarding overriding 'intention' option when creating a form, and it worked great. Basically, when I created CSRF token I used 'delete' for its intention parameter. And then when I created a form to use its isValid() function during form processing, I overridden the 'intention' option by passing an array to the createBuilder('form', $data, array('intention' => 'delete')). Doing so solved my problem. THANK YOU!  It's surprising that Symfony2 does not really have documentation about this.

Answer (score 5):

Note: intention is no longer default to be unknown. When I checked this out in symfony 2.3, it would appear it to default to the type name:

`$options['intention'] ?: ($builder->getName() ?: get_class($builder->getType()->getInnerType()))`

It would be good if there was some programatic way to get the intention out that is used instead of having to rely on these defaults.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen that this is resolved but I have some form troubles too and saw an other post here :

[symfony2 CSRF invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442922/symfony2-csrf-invalid)

And their solution seems to me better than making my own token :

> There is no problem using {{ form_widget(form) }} to build your custom form. All you have to do is add the _token like this: {{ form_widget(form._token) }}

Comment: this works when you do *have* the form in your twig, which for me is not always the case.. (although that could be against good symfony practice..?)

Answer (score 0):

My solution using Symfony 2.8:

in the action Controller (when the form is submitted):

```
    $theToken = $request->get('Token');

    //Token Verification   
    $isValidToken = $this->isCsrfTokenValid('your_intention', $theToken);
    if ($isValidToken === false)
    {
        // Error
    }
```

check this page where I found the info: 
http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Csrf/CsrfProvider/CsrfProviderInterface.html#method_isCsrfTokenValid